# How is power and communication from USB achieved at the same time?

Tags: usb

I am currently designing a circuit which is powered from USB but also requires the ability to communicate (from the PC) to the microcontroller using UART or rs232 over the USB cable. How is this achieved?

[Edit] I am using the BC04 module (http://www.electrodragon.com/w/index.php?title=BC04#Application) I simply want to be able to send it AT commands over the USB cable

Comment: USB has a seperate 5V line, it might be worth including a few more details on where the problem is. Are you using some sort of pre-built RS232 to USB cable or making your own?

Comment: USB has 5V, D+, D-, GND lines. If you understand plain RS232 communication, then USB isn't much harder, just think like a bidirectional RS232 serial comm line, and a separate pair of wires to provide power to a device. Of course, that is a highly simplified explanation.

Comment: Sorry, I am a novice electronics student trying to develop a bluetooth device. Once I plug the device into the USB port of the computer to recharge the batteries I want to be able to modify the bluetooths settings using AT commands. Im guessing I can do this using either UART or RS232 communication.

Comment: @user28350, normally that's the USB CDC (communications device class) and shouldn't need extra hardware. You probably need some drivers so that the device ends up as a serial port that you can open with a terminal emulator. Maybe edit your question to include that and add what the exact devices involved are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One easy way to provide power and communicate with the device at the same time would be to use one of the FTDI [USB TTL Serial Cables](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/Cables/USBTTLSerial.htm). Make sure to pick a 3.3V device and as that device doesn't draw much current the [TTL-232RG-VSW3V3-WE](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/Cables/DS_TTL-232RG_CABLES.pdf) with an output of 3.3V at up to 50mA would be suitable.

The Wiki page for the product shows the minimum pin connections when using the serial interface in the first application circuit. Just much those up with the corresponding pin numbers / colours from the FTDI datasheet.

Once the FTDI drivers have been installed (if required you may already have them) you'll just require a terminal emulator to talk to the com port. I quite like [RealTerm](http://realterm.sourceforge.net/) as it has a nice set of features useful when debugging embedded systems.

Comment: Be aware that at higher baud rates, those FTDI cables can have problems.  The cable is too long for reliable TTL-level async signalling at speeds over 38.4kbps.

Comment: @markt - I have used many many of the TTL232R cables at 5V at baud rate of 115200 and had zero problems with the TTL-level signalling. This is in at least five separately designed applications.